# Quarkus Restclient throws javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type <my-interface> and qualifiers [@Any]

Tags: java, quarkus, rest-client

I am trying to integrate a second rest client to my micro service and am getting an error.

```
@RegisterRestClient
public interface <my-interface> {
@POST
@Path("/example")
Response postStuff(DataBean data);
}
```

The injection class does it as follows:

```
@Inject @Any
protected <my-interface> api;
```

Following is the error msg:

```
 javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type <my-class> and qualifiers [@Any]
```

I have seen this issue pop up a lot but adding @ApplicationScoped or @Singleton does not work for me. As I understand the @Path annotation should make the interface discoverable. My other interface does not have any issues and I cannot imagine why.

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: did you add @ApplicationScoped to the class which you inject <my-interface> api?

Comment: yes I did. Sadly no difference

Comment: another thing may be that scope is not defined in application.properties? like here: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-configuration

Comment: Hello, could it be caused by the access control keyword 'protected' when injecting ?

Comment: Yes i forgot the scope. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 4):

Use the `@RestClient` annotation for injection:

```
@RestClient
protected <my-interface> api;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Kerim said. You need to define the scope in the application.properties as described here: [Using the rest client: Create the configuration (Quarkus)](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-configuration)

Comment: So I just added the scope to the application.properties and I'm running into the same issue. This is only the case while compiling with quarkus:test. Protected should not be an issue bc the other API is also injected as protected. Can Quarkus only use one API per service?

Comment: Is there a better way to contact multiple APIs? I know I could use @Path to specify the URLs, but I need to specify the URLs in the application.properties